# reducible Problem on Zp

Tags: ring-theory

Show that $x^4+1$ is reducible over $Z_p$ for every prime $p$.i have done it for $p=2,3$.but no idea as to how to do for general $p$??

Comment: Is that the field of finite order or is it the localization? Considering that it *isn't* irreducible over $\Bbb Z/(2)$, I'm wondering if you mean the latter.

Comment: See http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/69482.html
If $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $-1 \equiv a^2 \pmod p$ for some $a \in \Bbb{Z}_p$, so $-a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$.
$x^4 + 1 \equiv x^4 - a^2 \equiv (x^2 - a)(x^2 + a) \pmod p$, which is reducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, $x^4+1$ is *reducible* modulo every prime.

Indeed, since the product of two quadratic nonresidues is a quadratic residue, at least one of $-1, -1/2, 1/2$ is a quadratic residue modulo any odd prime $p$.

If $-1=a^2$, then $x^4+1 = x^4 - a^2 = (x^2 - a)(x^2+a)$.

If $-1/2 = a^2$, then $x^4 + 1 = x^4 - 4a^4 = (x^2-2a^2)(x^2+2a^2)$.

If $1/2 = a^2$, then $x^4 + 1 = x^4 + 4a^4 = (x^2+2ax+2a^2)(x^2-2ax+2a^2)$.

$p=2$ is handled separately: $x^4 + 1 = (x+1)^4$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $p=2$ we have that $(1)^4+1\equiv 0$ mod $2$. Thus it is not irreducible over $\mathbb {Z}/(2) $.

So your statement is false.

Comment: sorry .i had a mistake .indeed we have to prove that it is reducible for every prime p